# Widget Test Failing despite Bloc successfully triggers a state change

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenraio**

I have a very simple scenario, where a bloc is used to toggle an icon. The state management works fine on the app. However, when I run a widget test, it fails even after detecting a relevant event trigger from the button tap.

**Code**

```
testWidgets('ShowHide toggle', (tester) async {
      // Arrange
      when(() => mockShowHideBloc.state).thenReturn(
        const HideState(isHide: true),
      );

      // Act
      await tester.pumpWidget(const MainApp());
      // await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(const LoginPage()));
      await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget2(const LoginPage()));

      Finder showHideFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey('ShowHide'));
      Finder hideIconFinder = find.byIcon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined);
      Finder showIconFinder = find.byIcon(Icons.visibility_outlined);

      // Assert
      expect(showHideFinder, findsOneWidget);
      expect(hideIconFinder, findsOneWidget);
      expect(showIconFinder, findsNothing);

      // Act
      await tester.tap(showHideFinder);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      // Assert
      verify(() => mockShowHideBloc.add(ShowHideToggle())).called(1);
      await expectLater(showHideFinder, findsOneWidget);
      await expectLater(hideIconFinder, findsNothing); // ---> Test fails here
      await expectLater(showIconFinder, findsOneWidget);
    });
```

**Problem**

I get the following error message:

**══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: no matching candidates
Actual: _IconWidgetFinder:<Found 1 widget with icon "IconData(U+0F4A0)":**

I guess this means that the widget test still finds the `hideIconFinder`. I have tried with both `expect` and `await expectLater` but get the same failure message.

**Request**

I would like to know what is wrong in my code that causes the test to fail and how to fix it.

Comment: post minimal reproducible codes